# Uncaught ReferenceError: pagination is not defined. Как исправить?

Tags: javascript, mootools

Uncaught ReferenceError: pagination is not defined. Как исправить? Уже бьюсь целый день, ошибка возникает на этой странице - http://104.236.19.82/index.php/credits. И из-за ошибки не работает пагинатор внизу страницы. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: pagination is not defined - означает, что скрипт пытается вызвать переменную, которая не определена ( ее нет в скрипте, определена в другом месте )
P.S. у меня другую ошибку выдает

Comment: Вы видимо используете другой браузер, не Google Chrome.